# How to use Castle Windsor with ASP.Net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am trying to wire up dependency injection with Windsor to standard asp.net web forms. I think I have achieved this using a HttpModule and a CustomAttribute (code shown below), although the solution seems a little clunky and was wondering if there is a better supported solution out of the box with Windsor?

There are several files all shown together here

```
    // index.aspx.cs
    public partial class IndexPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Write("page loading");
        }

        [Inject]
        public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    }

    // WindsorHttpModule.cs
    public class WindsorHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private HttpApplication _application;
        private IoCProvider _iocProvider;

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            _application = context;
            _iocProvider = context as IoCProvider;

            if(_iocProvider == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Application must implement IoCProvider");
            }

            _application.PreRequestHandlerExecute += InitiateWindsor;
        }

        private void InitiateWindsor(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Page currentPage = _application.Context.CurrentHandler as Page;
            if(currentPage != null)
            {
                InjectPropertiesOn(currentPage);
                currentPage.InitComplete += delegate { InjectUserControls(currentPage); };
            }
        }

        private void InjectUserControls(Control parent)
        {
            if(parent.Controls != null)
            {
                foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
                {
                    if(control is UserControl)
                    {
                        InjectPropertiesOn(control);
                    }
                    InjectUserControls(control);
                }
            }
        }

        private void InjectPropertiesOn(object currentPage)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = currentPage.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                object[] attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (InjectAttribute), false);
                if(attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                {
                    object valueToInject = _iocProvider.Container.Resolve(property.PropertyType);
                    property.SetValue(currentPage, valueToInject, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Global.asax.cs
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication, IoCProvider
    {
        private IWindsorContainer _container;

        public override void Init()
        {
            base.Init();

            InitializeIoC();
        }

        private void InitializeIoC()
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer();
            _container.AddComponent<ILogger, Logger>();
        }

        public IWindsorContainer Container
        {
            get { return _container; }
        }
    }

    public interface IoCProvider
    {
        IWindsorContainer Container { get; }
    }
```

Comment: Just like to say thanks for the code above as it allowed me to create an MVP framework for some legacy webforms code.

Comment: Not a problem Keith.. glad it could be of some use to someone

Comment: i tried this code, but it actually clears the ViewState on every request. It seems that if you access the Controls property of the current Page before the Load event, ASP.NET is unable to restore the ViewState during the LoadViewState stage between the Init and Load (see forums.asp.net/p/1043999/1537884.aspx). I believe this is why Ayende uses the Init event in base classes for Page, MasterPage, and UserControl, respectively, to resolve any IoC dependencies.

Comment: interesting.. thanks for the update. I have actually been using the method you describe after the advice below to look at igloo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you're basically on the right track - If you have not already I would suggest taking a look at Rhino Igloo, an WebForms MVC framework, [Here's a good blog post on this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/09/03/Rhino-Igloo-ndash-MVC-Framework-for-Web-Forms.aspx) and the source is [here](https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/rhino-igloo) - Ayende (the Author of Rhino Igloo) tackles the issue of using Windsor with webforms quite well in this project/library.

I would cache the reflection info if you're going to inject the entire nested set of controls, that could end up being a bit of a performance hog I suspect.

Last of all spring.net approaches this in a more configuration-oriented way, but it might be worth taking a look at their implementation - here's a good [reference blog post](http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=70) on this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modified version of the OP's code that (i) caches injected properties to avoid repeated reflection calls, (ii) releases all resolved components, (iii) encapsulates container access so as not to expose implementation.

```
// global.asax.cs
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private static IWindsorContainer _container;

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        _container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
    }

    internal static object Resolve(Type type)
    {
        return _container.Resolve(type);
    }

    internal static void Release(object component)
    {
        _container.Release(component);
    }

    //...
}

// WindsorHttpModule.cs
public class WindsorHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    // cache the properties to inject for each page
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]> InjectedProperties = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>();
    private HttpApplication _context;

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += InjectProperties;
        _context.EndRequest += ReleaseComponents;
    }

    private void InjectProperties(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentPage = _context.Context.CurrentHandler as Page;
        if (currentPage != null)
        {
            InjectProperties(currentPage);
            currentPage.InitComplete += delegate { InjectUserControls(currentPage); };
        }
    }

    private void InjectUserControls(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (control is UserControl)
            {
                InjectProperties(control);
            }
            InjectUserControls(control);
        }
    }

    private void InjectProperties(Control control)
    {
        ResolvedComponents = new List<object>();
        var pageType = control.GetType();

        PropertyInfo[] properties;
        if (!InjectedProperties.TryGetValue(pageType, out properties))
        {
            properties = control.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectAttribute), false).Length > 0)
                .ToArray();
            InjectedProperties.TryAdd(pageType, properties);
        }

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var component = Global.Resolve(property.PropertyType);
            property.SetValue(control, component, null);
            ResolvedComponents.Add(component);
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseComponents(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var resolvedComponents = ResolvedComponents;
        if (resolvedComponents != null)
        {
            foreach (var component in ResolvedComponents)
            {
                Global.Release(component);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<object> ResolvedComponents
    {
        get { return (List<object>)HttpContext.Current.Items["ResolvedComponents"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items["ResolvedComponents"] = value; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started at a company where there are a lot of legacy webform apps, so this looks to be a real interesting approach, and could offer a way forward if we wanted to add DI to existing web pages, thanks.

One point I noticed is that the Injection method uses the container.Resolve to explicitly resolve components, therefore I think we may need to do a container.Release on the components when the Page Unloads.

If we have transient components and don't do this then we may face memory leakages. Not sure how components with Per Web Request lifestyles would behave (i.e. would Windsor pick them up at the end of the web request, even though we explicitly resolved them) but here too may want to play safe.

Therefore the module may need to be extended to keep track of the components that it resolves and release them so that Windsor knows when to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that was missing from the accepted answers was the fact that the http module needs to be registered in the web.config file (depending on the application) before the module will actually resolve the dependencies on the code-behind pages. What you need is :

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ClassNameForHttpModuleHere" type="NamespaceForClass"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Other than that the accepted solutions worked like a charm.

Reference to the Microsoft website for adding http modules: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Rather than doing it like this, you could also use a type resolver directly with something like:

```
ILogger Logger = ResolveType.Of<ILogger>();
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for the answer.. do you have any links or more information for this ResolveType?

Comment: This isn't really dependency _injection_, now is it? :)