# Can I use an IoC container to create ASP.NET webforms pages and controls?

Tags: asp.net, ioc-container, webforms

With ASP.NET MVC it is pretty easy to integrate an IoC container to create the controllers.

Is the same thing also possible with webforms to create the pages and controls and pass them any dependencies? If yes, where do I have to plug it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, as Web Forms does not allow any code to take control of Page and Control instantiation. So something like a Page Factory is not feasible, and you can't do constructor injection.

But there are work arounds/hacks that can buy you setter injection as others have mentioned.

Comment: Downvoter: please tell me how my answer is wrong so I can learn from my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, here's an example of how [Spring.NET does it](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/10/enabling-dependency-injection-in-web.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) was the first major IoC container for ASP.NET. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293790/how-to-use-castle-windsor-with-asp-net-web-forms) question discussing how it can be used with Web forms.

Answer (score 1):

Another good approach would be using the [Model-View-Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx) pattern and have your dependencies injected into the presenter's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but in the .NET Framework 4.7.2+ you can have constructor injection in ASP.NET WebForm pages and user controls.

From [this official blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/06/05/use-dependency-injection-in-webforms-application/):

> ### Areas that Dependency Injection can be used
>
> There are many areas you can use Dependency Injection in WebForms applications now. Here is a complete list.
>
> - Pages and controls WebForms page User control Custom control
> - `IHttpHandler` and `IHttpHandlerFactory`
> - `IHttpModule` Providers
> - BuildProvider
> - `ResourceProviderFactory`
> - Health monitoring provider
> - Any `ProviderBase` based provider created by `System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider`. e.g. custom session state provider