# GridView: TemplateField + LinkButton does not fire RowCommand event but ButtonField does

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding, webforms

I have a `GridView` with a `TemplateField` in which resides a `LinkButton`.

My problem is that for some reason this `LinkButton` does not cause the `OnRowCommand` event to fire.

The plot thickens: when I experimented by adding a `ButtonField`, that **does** fire the `OnRowCommand` event (but I dont think I can use it because I don't think I can add data-bound expressions e.g. for the text of the button).

Here is the column with the `LinkButton`:

```
            <asp:TemplateField     
            HeaderText="Customer #:"
            SortExpression="custNumber"
            HeaderStyle-Width="8em">                               
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton runat="server"                                
                    Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custNumber")%>' 
                    CommandName="viewCustomerDetails"
                    CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "custNumber")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>                     
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

And here in all its complexity is the `ButtonField`:

```
                <asp:ButtonField
            Text="buttonField"
            CommandName="viewCustomerDetails"
            />
```

So those seem like the relevant facts:

1. It doesn't *seem* to have anything to do with JS - I opened the page in Google Chrome with Adblock and one by one blocked each JS script and nothing happened
2. I can't get `LinkButton` to fire the `OnRowCommand` event, even when there are no databound expressions in the `Text` or `CommandArgument` attributes.
3. I can get `ButtonField` to fire the `OnRowCommand` event without changing anything else whatsoever.
4. We have Ektron.

So those are the symptoms. Anyone have a diagnosis?

P.S. - it's not lupus.

**EDIT: As per Wiktor's very helpful suggestion, I checked the client side outputs. For the linkButton, the second parameter to doPostBack() [which the ButtonField has as the command name] is BLANK.**

So now the question becomes: why on earth is this blank? :/

**EDIT the second: It also appears that the first argument is slightly different as well.**

Here is the client code output by the `ButtonField` (again, this one *works* and does fire OnRowCommand):

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$theContent$thePageContent2$SubContent3$MyPanel$gvActiveCustomers','viewCustomerDetails$0')">buttonField</a>
```

Now here is the client code output by the `LinkButton`:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$theContent$thePageContent2$SubContent3$MyPanel$gvActiveCustomers$ctl02$ctl00','')">1234567890 </a>
```

The two main differences:
1. LinkButton doesn't get a 2nd argument for some reason;
2. the first argument is also different - notice how the buttonField ends at "gvActiveCustomers", but the LinkButton specifies "gvActiveCustomers$ct102$ct100"

**If I change the arguments to __doPostBack on the LinkButton to match the arguments on the ButtonField, the LinkButton fires OnRowCommand.**

So why would the arguments become different in the first place?

Comment: Can you check the page source and find out what is the client-side output of these link buttons? Are they correctly rendered as anchors with `onclick='__doPostback(,,,`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla - see edit. Thanks for your suggestion! That definitely reveals a lot more about the nature of the problem!

Comment: Odd, indeed. What if you put anything, like "5", there?

Comment: @WiktorZychla - see second edit. Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: Another difference is that you are giving an explicit ID to your link button. I don't have the VS at hand so that I can't verify anything but could you possibly remove the ID from the link button?

Comment: @WiktorZychla - yeah I thought of that too. I removed it and it made no difference :( I removed it in the question to match the code.

Comment: Will check that tomorrow.

Comment: Can you show the complete markup of GridView. Also show how you DataBind the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick Question! (sorry - I can assure you it wasn't *intended* to be)

The culprit turned out to be a module for Dependency Injection using Castle Windsor that looked very similar to this [How to use Castle Windsor with ASP.Net web forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293790/how-to-use-castle-windsor-with-asp-net-web-forms)

As you can see from a highly rated comment on the original question, the code clears out the ViewState on every request. ("Well there's your problem!")

Since this is a thoroughly unsatisfying answer to anyone who may have wanted to solve this question as a puzzle of sorts, here is the method I used to find it:

- Creating a separate simple File > New Project spike to confirm that GridViews were firing OnRowCommand properly on my machine at all. Unsurprisingly, this worked.
- Removing *everything* that could possibly be affecting the GridView from within the application pages itself by creating a new page with nothing but a grid view and a "it worked" message OnRowCommand. OnRowCommand still didn't fire.
- At this point, I conclude it has to be some sort of "spooky action at a distance" - i.e. the 2D Flatlanders that are the classes in the system are being mysteriously poked by a finger in the third dimension that they know nothing of. First suspect? web.config
- Replace web.config with the completely out-of-the-box default web.config from my earlier spike. Thankfully, this didn't hose the whole project and cause it not to run at all. Also thankfully, OnRowCommand now fires on the simple page! *Now we're getting somewhere.*
- So we know it's something in web.config. Put the original (non-working) web.config back. Now to try some bisection so we can eliminate as much as possible with each run of the system. Comment out the first half of the system.web element, still works. Comment out second half, still works. So we know it's not in system.web...
- Lather, rinse, repeat until when we run the test on the simple page it starts to work.
- When it starts to work, you know that the problem lies in one or more of the elements that you just commented out. Keep bisecting until you find the individual line or lines responsible.

In our case it turned out to be an element in system.webService > modules (the aforementioned dependency injection module).

Comment: Do you mean system.WebServer?